# Cloud9 environment variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, cloud9-ide, env

I am developing a Rails 4 app on cloud9 (c9.io). When I placed `SECRET="geheim"` in config file, it works fine. I tried setting an environment variable using

```
echo "export SECRET=geheim" >> ~/.profile
```

and then using `ENV['SECRET']` in config file, but it doesn't work. When I type `printenv SECRET` in console, it returns nothing, meaning the variable is not set. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using the figaro gem?

Comment: At the terminal prompt, `export SECRET=geheim`.

Answer (score 4):

You can add environment variables on cloud9 only if you are using the run panel to run your application. In the run panel theres a ENV button at the far right side where you can set your environment variables.

Heres some documentation about setting up your run command:
https://docs.c9.io/v1.0/docs/run-an-application

Unfortunately, this doesnt work if you're running your app from the terminal as cloud9 doesnt seem to support environment variables directly from the  terminal.

Comment: steve's suggestion for using the terminal to enter `export SECRET=geheim` will work

Comment: Thanks for the above comment helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

In the linux terminal:

```sh
% export <env-variable-name> = <env-variable-value>
```

For example, setting an AWS-S3 bucket:

```sh
% export PHOTOS_BUCKET='s3://edx-photo-lab/photos/'
```

source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/env-vars.html 

The above solution has the problem that the variables are cleared when the Cloud9 EC2 is rebooted.
To persist the variable you must add the `export` statement to the `~/.bashrc`. You could use vim for edit:

```sh
% sudo vim ~/.bashrc
```